# Is it possible to use Gatsby plugins outside of a Gatsby build?

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin

As a locally-run preparation step, I've got some CSV that I want to convert into JSON for a Gatsby site. I know that I can set up my `gatsby-config.js` render data from CSV using `gatsby-transformer-csv` but what I want to do is use that plugin ± **directly** outside of my main Gatsby build.

Something like:

```
import { onCreateNode as csvTransform } from "gatsby-transformer-csv/gatsby-node";
import { createFileNodeFromBuffer } from "gatsby-source-filesystem";



async function convertTheThings(csvContent: Buffer) {
  const csvNode = await createFileNodeFromBuffer({
    buffer: csvContent
  });


  await csvTransform({
    node: csvNode,
    actions // FIXME: how to get these!?
  });
  
  // … use the individual JSON nodes …
  for (const jsonNode of jsonNodesCreated) {
     await writeFile(`data/processed_content/${jsonNode.name}.json`, jsonNode.content);
  } 
}
```

But it seems that there is no way to "call into" Gatbsy and use it like a more traditional library? Is there an API that lets me use and manipulate nodes without being part of the main actual static build?